# Array Outofbounds exception

Tags: java, arrays

im getting a out of bounds error on line 57. any help is appreciated. the program takes 1 integer and creates and array with that many indexes. it then asks for more integers to fill it up. it then takes all the even numbers and places it into a second array with is then outputted.

```
run:
Enter the ammount of integers you will require.
10
Enter your integers: 
1
Enter your integers: 
2
Enter your integers: 
3
Enter your integers: 
4
Enter your integers: 
5
Enter your integers: 
6
Enter your integers: 
7
Enter your integers: 
8
Enter your integers: 
9
Enter your integers: 
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at AllEven.arrcheck2(AllEven.java:57)
    at AllEven.main(AllEven.java:24)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

**CODE**

```
import java.util.*;

public class AllEven {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int read;

    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the ammount of integers you will require.");

    read = kybd.nextInt();

    int[] arr1 = new int[read];
    int[] arr2;

    int count = 0;
    arrRead(arr1);
    arrcheck(arr1);

    arr2 = new int[count];

    arrcheck2(arr1, arr2);
    mainPrint(arr2);



}

public static int arrcheck(int[] arr1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] % 2 == 0) {
            count++;

        }

    }
    return count;
}

public static void arrRead(int[] arr1) {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your integers: ");
        arr1[i] = kybd.nextInt();

    }
}

public static void arrcheck2(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] % 2 == 0) {
            arr2[j] = arr1[i];
            j++;

        }

    }

}

public static void mainPrint(int[] arr2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Printing Even Numbers.");
        System.out.println(arr2[i]);
    }
}
}
```

ok so thanks everyone who helped, But now after the integers have been inputted the program just finishes without displaying anything after.

Comment: add comment in code where it actually fails

Comment: The error message says what you are doing wrong. You try to acces an index number in the array that's bigger than the length of the array. Put some System.out.println(...) in your code and than you probably see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the return value of `arrcheck` invocation in count variable before creating `arr2`. Otherwise, you would create your `arr2` with size 0.

Change: -

```
int count = 0;
arrRead(arr1);
arrcheck(arr1);
```

to: -

```
arrRead(arr1);
int count = arrcheck(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you have your `arrcheck` function returning a count and not doing anything with it.  I suspect you meant to write something like this:

```
arrRead(arr1);
int count = arrcheck(arr1);
```

otherwise your next line:

```
arr2 = new int[count];
```

creates an array of size 0 which will cause array out of bounds as soon as it is accessed.

Also you spelled Amount wrong, I think the rest of the program should work with the above change.

Answer (score 1):

After brief look at the code I think your problem lies here:

```
int count = 0;
arrRead(arr1);
arrcheck(arr1);

arr2 = new int[count]; //array of size 0!

arrcheck2(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `arr2` as a zero-length array:

```
int count = 0;
....
arr2 = new int[count];
```

Then, in `arrcheck2` you have the line:

```
arr2[j] = arr1[i];
```

This will not work because `arr2` has no length so you cannot put anything into it.

Answer (score 1):

The size of arr2 is 0. so when you try to access a non existing index in it you get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You create an array with length 0.

```
arr2 = new int[count];
```

You should give it a length bigger than 0.
If you want it to be the same length as arr1 just do `arr2 = new int[read];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize arr2 to the same length as arr1. int count = read will fix the issue. Or you can remove count entirely and just use read when initializing the array.

```
    read = kybd.nextInt();

    int[] arr1 = new int[read];
    int[] arr2;

    int count = read;
    arrRead(arr1);
    arrcheck(arr1);

    arr2 = new int[count];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing your array `int[] arr2`.  You should not use an array to populate even elements from the initial array because arrays require a determined size upon initialization -- you are better off using `ArrayList` and then conver it into an array once you know the definitive size, if you must.